# How can I use an own class for Console.WriteLine override?

Tags: c#, overriding

I want my `ConsoleEngine` class to handle the `Console.WriteLine()` Method. How do I have to prepare my ConsoleEngine class to override the `WriteLine()` method?

Comment: Write a wrapper class, and call console methods in it.... No need to override the methods....

Comment: He don't want to output in the console but use the console.write() command to output the content somewhere else

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a class that derives from `TextWriter`:

```
public class MyWriter : TextWriter
{
    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        //Do something, like write to a file or something
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        //Do something, like write to a file or something
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get 
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII;
        }
    }
}
```

and set the `Console` output to an instance of that class:

```
Console.SetOut(new MyWriter());
```

Comment: If you override the `void Write(char value)` method, you don't need to override the `void Write(string value)` method since the method which takes a `char` will be called for every character.

Comment: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'