# How can I build efficient logging for a C# console app?

Tags: c#, logging

I've built a console app for EWS email processing and file delivery. I'd like to build some logging for this without having to put hundreds of StreamWriter lines. Is there a way to log everything that is printed to the screen? PowerShell can do this, so I was hoping that C# had the same functionality. My Google search "C# log all console text and errors" didn't yield anything great, and I'm not sure how else to reword the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace your Console.WriteLine calls with a call to a method that does both logging and output.

Comment: You can override Console.WriteLine method and place your logger there. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661000/how-can-i-use-an-own-class-for-console-writeline-override

Comment: I really do think a decent Logging Framework cannot harm. Look into NLog or Serilog. Both of which have Console Targets/Sinks, even colored.

Comment: @Ralf I had considered that, but I think I'll still miss something. I want to make sure I capture *absolutely everything* that is on the screen, whether it is a Consol.WriteLine or an Error, or anything else that happens to make it to the screen.

Comment: Install a "tee" derivate? So you can forward the output to a file and see it still on the console?  I wouldn't call that logging then but maybe what you want. You don't have to touch your code.

Comment: ^^ Then make sure all pipes are redirected. StdOut _and_ StdErr... But again: I cannot think of anything more proper than a logging framework. Yes, you might do a major refactoring to MS Logging API (I would recommend) and then configure logging. But from then on it's piece of cake. You want to see logs in Console: Add the COnsole sink. You want everything in a File: Add File Sink. You want it in a DB, EventLog, Cloud-Service ... add the sink and you're done.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. I know how to create a class, use functions, or write errors to accomplish this. I was just asking if there was a way to log EVERYTHING on the screen like PowerShell does with Start-Transcript.

Comment: @LordHelmet you'll probably find that hijacking the various standard IO streams is how powershell does it, too.

Comment: @Rook, yeah, PowerShell is sort of a hack of a language. Took me a while to accept its haphazard nature.